# Why does this not write to file correctly?

Tags: python, text-files

With the file `crop data.txt` containing this:

```
Lettuce 1 2 3 
Tomato 4 5 6
```

When I run the code and input `Tomato` and `9` instead of removing `6` and inserting `9` after `Tomato` like it should, it replaces the whole contents of the file with `9`, so that it is like this:

```
9
```

I'm not sure why it does this and how to fix it.

```
crop = input('Which crop? ') 
quantity = input('How much? ') 

file = ('cropdata.txt')

if crop in open(file).read():
 with open(file, 'r') as file_read:
       lines = []
       for line in file_read:
           if crop in line:
               line = str(line.rstrip("\n"))
               line_parts = line.split(" ")
               print (len(line_parts))
               if len (line_parts) > 4:
                   print('len greater')
                   line_parts.remove (line_parts[3])
                   line_parts.insert (1, quantity)
                   line = str(line_parts[0]+ line_parts[1] +
                   line_parts[2]+ line_parts[3] + ' ' + '/n')
               else:
                    print('len less than') 
                    line = str(quantity + " "  + "\n")
       lines.append(line)

with open(file, 'w') as file_rewrite:
    file_rewrite.writelines(lines)
else:
    print('crop not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

At least your indentation wrong in two places, try this to get all lines:

```
crop = input('Which crop? ') 
quantity = input('How much? ') 

file = ('cropdata.txt')

if crop in open(file).read():
 with open(file, 'r') as file_read:
       lines = []
       for line in file_read:
           if crop in line:
               line = str(line.rstrip("\n"))
               line_parts = line.split(" ")
               print (len(line_parts))
               if len (line_parts) > 4:
                   print('len greater')
                   line_parts.remove (line_parts[3])
                   line_parts.insert (1, quantity)
                   line = str(line_parts[0]+ line_parts[1] +  line_parts[2]+ line_parts[3] + ' ' + '/n')
               else:
                   print('len less than') 
                   line = str(quantity + " "  + "\n")
           lines.append(line)

with open(file, 'w') as file_rewrite:
    file_rewrite.writelines(lines)
else:
    print('crop not found')
```